# Keep item in list for certain time

Tags: redis

I am no an expert in redis at all. Today I run into one idea, but I don't know if it is possible in redis.

I want to store list of values but only for some time, for example list of ip addresses which visited page in last 5 minutes. As far as I know I can't set `EXPIRE` on single list/hash item, right? So I am pushing `1`, `2`, `3` into list/hash but after certain constant time I want each item to expire/disapear? Or maybe instead of list hash structure will be more suitable `{ '1': timestamp-when-disapear, ... }`?

Or maybe only solution is

```
SET test.1.1 1
EXPIRE test.1.1 60
SET test.1.2 2
EXPIRE test.1.2 60
SET test.1.3 3
EXPIRE test.1.3 60
# to retrieve, can I pipeline KEYS output to MGET?
KEYS test.1.*
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a sorted set instead.

log the server IP along with the timestamp in a sorted set. During retrieval make use of that timestamp to get things you need. In a scheduler periodically delete keys which goes beyond the range.

Example:

```
zadd test 1465371055 1.1
zadd test 1465381055 1.3
zadd test 1465391055 1.1
```

your sorted set will have 1.1 and 1.3, where 1.1 is with the new value 1465391055.

Now on retrieval use

```
zrangebyscore test min max 
min -> currenttime - (5*60*1000)
max -> currenttime
```

you will get IP's visited in last 5 mins.

In another scheduler kind of thread you need to delete unwanted entries.

```
zremrangebyscore test min max
min -> currenttime - (10*60*1000) -> you can give it to any minute you want.
max -> currenttime
```

Also understand that if number of distinct IP's are too large then the sorted set will grow rapidly. Your scheduler thread must work properly to keep the memory in control.